# Parallelize oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle query using WITH, UNION and JOIN. How to Parallelize this.

Writing an example query here:

```
 SELECT NAME, Id, Salary, Type 
   FROM
      ( WITH Emp as 
         ( 
           SELECT E.Name, E.Id, E.Salary 
             From EMPLOYEE E 
       INNER JOIN  SALARY S
               ON E.Id=S.Id
            WHERE E.SEX='M'
          )

      SELECT Name, Id, Salary, 'High Salary' as Type 
        FROM Emp
       WHERE Salary >= '50000'

   UNION ALL
      SELECT Name, Id, Salary, 'Average Salary' as Type 
        FROM Emp
       WHERE Salary >= '10000'AND Salary <= '50000'

   UNION ALL
      SELECT Name, Id, Salary, 'Low Salary' as Type 
        FROM Emp
       WHERE Salary >= '10000' 
         AND Salary <= '50000' 
    ) A
```

In My Original Query, I'm having about 4 tables to Join and 10 UNION ALL Statements. Please suggest to parallelize this.

Comment: Need some more clarity because we dont get use of Join here,

Comment: Updated the Query with INNER JOIN

Comment: Why separate the three last selects. Use just a big select with a case for the type column. CASE WHEN Salary >= '50000'
  THEN  'High Salary' WHEN Salary >= '10000'AND Salary <= '50000' THEN 'Average Salary' ELSE 'Low Salary' END

Comment: With my approach you would have avoided completely the with. But just in case you can test the materialize HINT http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialize_sql_hint.htm

Comment: This is just an example query, In my main query I can't use Case condition. It has many business logics. So I need to use UNION ALL. Now I'm tuning the query. So that I'm trying Parallelization.

Comment: In the absence of showing the actual query, schema, and current execution plan, you're just asking "how do you use parallelism in Oracle", which is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0):

In 11gR2 it maybe this easy:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel */ NAME, Id, Salary, Type ...
```

But as David Aldridge mentioned, parallelism can be a broad topic.  This answer assumes you've got a long-running query that can benefit from parallelism, enough resources, sane configurations, Enterprise Edition, etc.  If the simple method doesn't work you'll need to come back and post the full query and explain plan.

For the specific `UNION ALL` case this query *may* benefit from [Concurrent Execution of Union All](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-1F4C90F9-3EF5-423A-B55B-2593FB3F1433.htm), a new features in 12c.  Although that feature seems mostly intended for querying remote databases.